# Distance Program Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

after finishing the midpoint program, I figured some good practice would be to just do a bunch more math formulas. And being as I'm doing advanced algebra this year, thought it woudlnt be a bad idea. So, I started to work on a Distance program, but I'm running into a random SyntaxError on line 8. Also, an explanation would be appreciated, being as I'm still very new to this. Thanks. edit: language is Python.

```
print("enter x1 value")
x1 = int(input("x1: "))
print("enter x2 value")
x2 = int(input("x2: "))
print("enter y1 value")
y1 = int(input("y1: "))
print("enter y2 value")
y2 = int(input("y2: "))
x = (x2 - x1)**
y = (y2 - y1)**
z = x + y
Distance = sqrt(z)
print(distance)
```

Comment: Replace `input()` with `raw_input()`

Comment: replace x = (x2 - x1)** by x = (x2 - x1)**2 and similarly the next line

Comment: The names `Distance` (penultimate line) and `distance` (last line) do not refer to the same value...